# Algolia: my records has an array of objects,how to access values of the array in template

Tags: javascript, algolia

my Algolia record has an array in it

```
 {
    "objectID": 345345,
    "title": "MyPost",
"url" : "myUrl" , 
    "tags": [{
        "tagID": "2444",
        "tagName": "tag1"
    },
    {
        "tagID": "2444",
        "tagName": "tag2"
    }}
```

how to access the TagID and tagName in each tag
I tried this but didn't work

```
<div class="hit article-content">   <h2> <a href="{{{url}}}">{{{title}}}</a>    </h2>
<strong>Tags:</strong>      
<a href="/smart/ar/tags/{{{tags[0].tagID}}}">{{{tags[0].tagName}}}</a>
<a href="/smart/ar/tags/{{{tags[1].tagID}}}">{{{tags[1].tagName}}}</a></div>
```

Comment: [algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) is a search API, not a templating language. Your question should be about the templating language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The comment of [76484](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3397771/76484) is correct, the question should probably not be tagged Algolia.

However, it seems like you're using a mustache-like templating engine. You can check [the documentation here](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html).

To display lists, you need to open a section and access its elements inside as variables.

```
<strong>Tags:</strong>      
{{#tags}}
  <a href="/smart/ar/tags/{{tagID}}">{{tagName}}</a>
{{/tags}}
```

To check if the list is empty, you can use an inverted section:

```
{{^tags}}
  No tags found
{{/tags}}
```

Also, you should only use triple braces `{{{` only when you're sure the input is HTML-safe. Otherwise, you should just use double braces `{{`, which will escape the content of the variable.